# Tool for creating resource file

Tags: c#, .net, dll

In our company we have a software program that operates the machines that we produce. The application (HMI) that is running on a WES7 OS is programmed in C#. Because our machines are shipped all over the world, the language of the HMI can be adjusted by clicking on a language button.

The HMI software is written by a third company but we have it in our own control now. The machine's we deliver might have project specific "fault" messages and must be added to the HMI. This means that these specific "fault messages" must be added to the resources.resx file. But for as far as I know, this can only be done from Visual Studio, do a build and a new file ExternalResources.xap file is created with all translations (Multilanguage).

We don't want a specific application for each customer or do a build on the project for only creating the ExternalResources.xap file. So I'm wondering if there are tools available that run standalone (no Visual Studio needed) and that can create the ExternalResources.xap file.

We don't need to add sources to the resources file, but only change the value of a source on project wish. I hope I made my point clear and someone knows a solution.

**Edit:**

I need to generatoe the ExternalResources.xap file. When you open this file, all locations available are shown in folders, and within this folders, there are  *.recourses.dll files. Those files do I need to generate!

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Resgen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccec7sz1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) 
Or develop some tool for that, here is a useful sample [Extended Strongly Typed Resource Generator](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13830/Extended-Strongly-Typed-Resource-Generator)
Hope this helps.